# optionSplit, match the middle item

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is it possible to match the middle item.
Like this:

```
a a ... b ... c c
```

The middle element get b and the rest a and c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could work only if count of `a` elements and `c` elements was constant ie.

```
a || a  |*|  b  |*|  c||c
```

this represents 2*a, many b, 2*c

Maybe just better solution will be creating small extension where you can use any available techniques of matching?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried, but maybe:

```
a |*| a || b || c |*| c
```